# In a comparison using のほうが, what does the second と mean?

Tags: grammar

I am working through Genki I and it has the sentence 日本とカナダとどちらのほうが寒いですか and I can't work out what the second と does. From what I understand, と is "and", so it sounds like it's saying "Of Japan and Canada **AND**, which is colder?" But I know that translation doesn't make sense.

Can anyone help me understand what that second と it doing? Thanks